# Sentiment Analysis - Cross Validation not valid score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, cross-validation

I am testing a Sentiment Analysis model using NLTK and SKlearn.

Movie_reviews data has "pos" and "neg" labels. For training the classifier I am using "featuresets". I am using cross validation on training data and accuracy on testing data. However cross validation is always much higher than accuracy. In the example below for logistic regression algorithm CV = 97 (average), Accuracy = 70. I have tested also with other algos and still cross validation very high.

I am pretty sure the code I have for cross validation is not right.

```
import nltk
import random 
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews  
from sklearn import cross_validation
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, SGDClassifier

documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
             for category in movie_reviews.categories()
             for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]
random.shuffle(documents)

all_words = []
for w in movie_reviews.words():
    all_words.append(w.lower())

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)
word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3000]

def find_features(document):
    words = set(document)
    features = {}
    for w in word_features:
        features[w] = (w in words)
    return features

featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev, category) in documents]        
training_set = featuresets[:1500]
testing_set =  featuresets[1500:]

cv = cross_validation.KFold(len(training_set), n_folds=10, shuffle=True, random_state=None)
LogisticRegression_classifier = SklearnClassifier(LogisticRegression())    
for traincv, testcv in cv:
    classifier = LogisticRegression_classifier.train(training_set[traincv[0]:traincv[len(traincv)-1]])
    print ('CV_accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, training_set[testcv[0]:testcv[len(testcv)-1]]))

print("LogisticRegression_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(LogisticRegression_classifier, testing_set))*100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **training_set[traincv[0]:traincv[len(traincv)-1]]** which means range from traincv[0] to traincv[len(traincv)-1]

In your case traincv[0] and testcv[0] will be always near to 0 and traincv[len(traincv)-1] and testcv[len(testcv)-1] will be near to 1499. So you are using almost same data for training and testing while doing N-Fold Validation.

Here, you actually need to use subset indexes which are there in traincv and testcv.

```
import numpy as np
training_set = np.array(training_set)
for traincv, testcv in cv:
    classifier = LogisticRegression_classifier.train(training_set[traincv])
    print ('CV_accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, training_set[testcv]
```

Comment: 1. smart way to find the average, is store the 10 results in a list.append and then use sum(list)/float(len(list)) ???

2. is it right calculate the confusion matrix only on the testing_set (linked with the accuracy on the testing_set) or it would be useful also calculate the confusion matrix for each cross validation?

Comment: 1. Better way for average is to keep adding 'accuracy' into 'accuracy_total' and divide it with KFold_Number. It will be faster and will require less memory. 
2. If you want to do some sort of analysis at the time of n_fold validation, it will be useful. So it all depends on your requirements/purpose.

Comment: done. can you share where I can improve the accuracy of the model? I mean play with the algos parameters and use stopwords